# flutter: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<Object?, Object?>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-functions

I get this error while serializing my json.
I am not sure I understand the error, but I have figured out that the code never reaches Prices.fromJson if I try to print something there. As you can see I am using Firebase Cloud Functions to return a data with nested data objects, and I struggle to get them serialized.

Code:

```
class Price {
  final DateTime validFrom;
  final DateTime validTo;
  final double nokPerKwh;

  const Price({
    required this.validFrom,
    required this.validTo,
    required this.nokPerKwh,
  });

  factory Price.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Price(
      validFrom: DateTime.parse(json['validFrom']),
      validTo: DateTime.parse(json['validTo']),
      nokPerKwh: json['nokPerKwh'],
    );
  }
}

class Prices {
  final double now;
  final Price lowest;
  final Price highest;

  const Prices({
    required this.now,
    required this.lowest,
    required this.highest,
  });

  factory Prices.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Prices(
      now: json['now'],
      lowest: Price.fromJson(json['lowest']),
      highest: Price.fromJson(json['highest']),
    );
  }
}

class ShowerCost {
  final DateTime time;
  final int minutes;
  final Prices prices;

  const ShowerCost({
    required this.time,
    required this.minutes,
    required this.prices,
  });

  factory ShowerCost.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    print(json); <--- {minutes: 20, time: 2022-02-07T23:46:41.625Z, prices: {now: 11.848, highest: null, lowest: {nokPerKwh: 1.1848, validFrom: 2022-02-08T00:00:00+01:00, validTo: 2022-02-08T01:00:00+01:00}}}
    return ShowerCost(
      time: DateTime.parse(json['time']),
      minutes: json['minutes'],
      prices: Prices.fromJson(json['prices']),
    );
  }
}

Future<ShowerCost> getShowerCost() async {
  try {
    HttpsCallable callable =
        FirebaseFunctions.instance.httpsCallable('getShowerCost');
    final results = await callable.call(<String, dynamic>{
      'minutes': 20,
      'time': DateTime.now().toIso8601String(),
      'minHour': DateTime(2022, 2, 7, 0).toIso8601String(),
      'maxHour': DateTime(2022, 2, 7, 23).toIso8601String()
    });
    return ShowerCost.fromJson(results.data);
  } catch (error) {
    print(error);
    return Future.error(error);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both @rapaterno's and @mohamed abu-ghazalla's answers pointed me into the right direction.
Conversion to `Map<String, dynamic>` using `Map<String, dynamic>.from(...)` needed to happen in all the child's `fromJson()` params:

```
factory Price.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  return Price(
    validFrom: DateTime.parse(json['validFrom']),
    validTo: DateTime.parse(json['validTo']),
    nokPerKwh: json['nokPerKwh'],
  );
}

factory Prices.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  return Prices(
    now: json['now'],
    lowest: Price.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic>.from(json['lowest'])),   <--- HERE
    highest: Price.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic>.from(json['highest'])), <--- HERE
  );
}

factory ShowerCost.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  return ShowerCost(
    time: DateTime.parse(json['time']),
    minutes: json['minutes'],
    prices: Prices.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic>.from(json['prices'])),  <--- HERE
  );
}

Future<ShowerCost> getShowerCost() async {
  try {
    HttpsCallable callable =
        FirebaseFunctions.instance.httpsCallable('getShowerCost');
    final results = await callable.call(<String, dynamic>{
      'minutes': 20,
      'time': DateTime.now().toIso8601String(),
      'minHour': DateTime(2022, 2, 8, 0).toIso8601String(),
      'maxHour': DateTime(2022, 2, 8, 23).toIso8601String()
    });
    return ShowerCost.fromJson(results.data);
  } catch (error) {
    print(error);
    return Future.error(error);
  }
}
```

Comment: This errors are completely annoying, thanks !

Answer (score 3):

You can use `json.decode` from `dart:convert` package.

```
    final results = await callable.call(<String, dynamic>{
      'minutes': 20,
      'time': DateTime.now().toIso8601String(),
      'minHour': DateTime(2022, 2, 7, 0).toIso8601String(),
      'maxHour': DateTime(2022, 2, 7, 23).toIso8601String()
    });
    // Try
    final data = Map<String, dynamic>.from(results.data) as Map<String, dynamic>
    // or
    final data = results.data.toMap()

    return ShowerCost.fromJson(data);
```

Comment: `json.decode()`expects a `String` while `results` is an `HttpsCallableResult<dynamic>`. This gives an error on `results`: `The argument type 'HttpsCallableResult<dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.`

Comment: oh sorry I meant results.data. Updated

Comment: I still get an error, but the last type has now changed to `String`: `type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'`

Comment: @MariusJ Could you check this code? If it doesn't work can you add the error logs to your post

Comment: `type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<Object?, Object?>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'`
I found a solution with both of your help, will be posting shortly. All the objects sent to the different `.fromJson()` methods need to be converted to `Map<String, dynamic>`, not just `results.data`. Thanks for pointing me into the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
final myMap = Map<String, dynamic>.from(results.data);
return Prices.fromJson(myMap);
```

Comment: I believe you meant returning `ShowerCost.fromJson(myMap)`. This throws the same error, unfortunately.